# android going to google maps from alert is going to current position first time instead of coordinates passed

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm making an android app that has a button on the home screen (fragment) that pops up an alert msg, where you can choose to go to launch Google maps (separate, not inside of my app) with the location you chose from the alert (I.E. alert pops up, you choose "Phoenix | Scottsdale). If maps has been prior to opening my app there's no problem and once you've chosen a location once, the second time it works.  However, the first time I go to the app and choose "Phoenix" it starts Google maps app and zooms in on my current location.

TLDR: Home fragment button => alert msg w/ 2 buttons for different locations => coords passed to google maps outside of app =>  first time use maps loads with current location and not my coords!

what am I doing wrong? how do I fix it?

```
Button fButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnLocations);
        fButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                // Set alert dialog body text and center
                TextView alertMsg = new TextView(getActivity());
                // TextView alertMsg = new TextView(activity here...);
                alertMsg.setText(R.string.choose_location);
                alertMsg.setTextSize(25);
                alertMsg.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

                // Create new alert dialog box builder
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity());

                // Set values of alert dialog box
                builder.setCancelable(true);
                //builder.setTitle(R.string.choose_location);
                builder.setView(alertMsg);
                builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

                // Set positive button value and action
                builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.phoenix, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        String url = "geo:33.484608,-112.060198?q=dummy location";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                // Set negative button value and action
                builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.scottsdale, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        String url = "geo:33.484608,-111.060198?q=dummy location";
                        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });

                // Create dialog box
                AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

                // Show dialog box on screen
                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you found a solution for this by any chance?